# Can I get the object upon which the each function has been called in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to refer to the object upon which a function has been called in Ruby?

For example, say I want to get the length of an array that I've called each on like so:

```
[1,2,3].each {|x| if <the_array>.length > 2 then { # do something } }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You could of course store it in a variable first, then use the variable inside the block while calling `.each` on the variable instead of the literal.

Comment: In your example, you specifically want to access the invocant inside a block that the method yields to. That is different to accessing it within the body of a method (which is trivial - `self`). Is your question only about blocks, as per your example (in which case Michael's comment covers normal way of doing what you need)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) like below :

```
[1,2,3].instance_eval {  self.each { |e| puts e >= self.size ? "foo" : "bar" } }
# >> bar
# >> bar
# >> foo
```

Comment: Hello, Arup. If you wish, you can drop `self.`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I kept those intentionally.. otherwise it will  look like something missing..

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-tap)?

```
[1,2,3].tap { |a| a.each {|x| puts "x = #{x}" if a.length > 2 } }
 # x = 1
 # x = 2
 # x = 3

[1,2].tap { |a| a.each {|x| puts "x = #{x}" if a.length > 2 } }
 # <nothing printed>
```